# Can't decide how correctly to use backend?

Tags: java, node.js, reactjs, express

In my project need to create the following architecture:
Front-End application is a web site resource that will combine HTML+React technologies. 
Back-End is a java application that will be connected to Mongo DB to operate with data. 
Now, in the middleware should be placed Node.js. And after reading a lot of info on the internet, I have now some confusions regarding this.
As I understand Frond-End will be routed to node.js (and now the question is it Express.js-- the same thing or it's different) which is also connected to Mongo Db and Java application(this is doing all logic).

Can someone explain me should use express.js with the integration of node.js in order to route to java server application?

Comment: Why do you need node.js as the middleware between your Java+MongoDB backend and React? And, are you assuming ExpressJS is necessary to work with React? If you don't need SSR and just a basic SPA with React, you can simplify your architecture by just using React as your frontend, and Java as the REST API

Comment: But i need to deploy my front end on node.js? yes ..or i can connect directly React to JAVA without any .JS? 
But it should be executed in some framework like express or node?

Comment: With static hosting, you can host a React App without node.js server, have you tried "compiling" a React App to a "build file"?. But if you really want to serve the static files (React) using a node server, there's no one stopping you. It must actually be the easier approach. For example, you have to understand your development setup will be different from production. You can develop your react app via create-react-app served @ localhost:3000, and I'm guessing your java api @ localhost:8080, but the react app must directly consume your java api.

Comment: When deploying to production, you have to build the react files, which will be served by your express server. With that, It's important to consider security and authentication; probably you would use JWT etc.. between your react app and java api

Comment: Yes thanks for clarification....will try to implement this aproach on real..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a middleware. Nodejs can help you do that in a lot of ways, you can use express.js so that you won't have to do more request/response parsing work. And when you want to connect to your java server using nodejs, you can also integrate that by calling the java server API endpoint by using some http library like [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) then you can directly communicate to java server app to directly communicate to the backend mongodb.

But your Front-End application can also directly communicate through your backend java by creating a REST API. And store all your business logic in the java REST API.

Comment: Thanks for an answer , i still can't vote but your answer is good enough.
Just to be sure that i understood you correctly.. I can use express.js either node.js and connect one of them to java server application that exposes REST API.
Is it correct?

Comment: Yup, if your java application exposes REST API, both node js or React application can directly communicate to the backend.